# Using rule with derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, rule

Assuming I have an expression like:

> D[a[t, r], r] + D[D[a[t, r], r],r] + D[D[a[t, r], t],r]

I would like to change variables, by expression everything in terms of `b = D[a[t,r],r]`
If I naively set a rule such as,

> myrule = D[a[t, r], r] -> b[t,r]

then, this will only correctly substitute it in for the first expression. 
Obviously, i could create a specific rule for each occurrence, but I was wondering if there was no nice way to make it work in general in a single go.

Comment: If you base the replacement on the `FullForm` of these terms, it'll be easier.

Comment: Your expression gets evaluated to `Derivative[0, 1][a][t, r] + Derivative[0, 2][a][t, r] + Derivative[1, 1][a][t, r]`, and the second term doesn't match your pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) an [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for `a`:

```
a /: Derivative[n_, 1][a] := Derivative[n, 0][b]
```

Then:

```
D[a[t, r], r] + D[D[a[t, r], r],r] + D[D[a[t, r], t],r] //TeXForm
```

> $b^{(0,1)}(t,r)+b^{(1,0)}(t,r)+b(t,r)$

Another possibility is:

```
Clear[a]
D[a[t, r], r] + D[D[a[t, r], r],r] + D[D[a[t, r], t],r] /. a->Derivative[0,-1][b] //TeXForm
```

> $b^{(0,1)}(t,r)+b^{(1,0)}(t,r)+b(t,r)$

Comment: Nice. Thank you.